# How to call a function when app is closed in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, background-mode

I need help, I do not know how to make a function call in the background when the application is closed, it only works if it is open or minimized.

```
platform.ready().then(() => { 
  this.backgroundMode.setDefaults({ silent: true });
  this.backgroundMode.enable();
  backgroundMode.on('enable').subscribe(() => { 
    setInterval(() => {
      this.getBusqueda();
    }, 5000);
  });
```

Comment: Help me understand what you're trying to achieve. You want to sent the app to the background & call a function as soon as it as moved into the background ? 

Or is there a scenario in which the app should call a function, when a condition is met, even if the app is in the background ?

Comment: Use Background Mode.

Comment: Thanks, I call a rest api when the app is closed, using the backgroundmode plugin works when change main app and send the app to background, but when the app is closed cant call the api